# How to query for Model in Django that is not referenced by another Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I would like to know how to make this query in Django's ORM. Consider the following models:

```
class Person(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    car = models.ManyToManyField("Automobile")

class Automobile(model.Models):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

I want to find all the *Automobile* that is NOT referenced by a Person. How does one do this in Django?
I thought of doing this:

```
am_no_person = []
for am in Automobile.objects.all():
    if not am.person_set.count():
        am_no_person.append(am)
```

But this looks so inefficient and wouldn't return a QuerySet object rather
a python list. Also this would be very slow on large data sets.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294213/django-get-all-objects-that-dont-belong-to-m2m ?

Comment: `Automobile.objects.filter(person__isnull=True)` ?

Comment: @warath-coder, the case is different since the one you gave has M2M relationship with itself, thus he can do a `subproducts__isnull=True`, in my case i cant do a `Automobile.objects.filter(person__isnull=True)` since there is no person attribute in Automobile, the relationship is from Person

Comment: it should... django makes the relationship, which you can control the name if you want by putting 'related_name=' in the Person M2M

Comment: now that was embarrassing, lol

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
all_persons = Person.objects.all().values_list('car__id', flat=True)
auto_without_pers = Automobile.objects.exclude(id__in=all_persons)
```

Because querysets are lazy loaded this would result in a single sql query.